# Can not rebuild file when file is changed with gulp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, gulp-watch

I use Gulp to run angularjs.
[image] 
I register "sass" task to compile `.scss` files

```
var paths = {
   app: 'app',
   dist: 'dist',
   component: 'app/bower_components'
};

gulp.task('sass', function() {
   return gulp
       .src(paths.app + '/css/**/*.scss')
       .pipe(sass())
       .pipe(minifyCss())
       .pipe(concat('main.css'))
       .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + '/css'));
});
```

And I use `gulp.watch` to re-build `.css` file when `.scss` file is changed.

```
gulp.task('watch:sass', function() {
   gulp.watch(paths.app + '/css/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

run task

```
gulp.task('run', function() {
  gulp.run(
    'build',
    'express',
    'watch:sass'
    );
});
```

But `.css` file didn't re-build when I changed `.scss` files?
Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: In your `sass` task, the part of the path you're appending has a leading slash (`/css/**/...`), whereas it doesn't in the `watch:sass` task (`css/**/...`). Might that be the problem?

Comment: thanks @robertklep, but it is not the problem. I edited it.

Comment: Could you show your directory structure?

Comment: Hi @RodyvanSambeek, I added image.

Comment: And the variable declarations of paths? Could you also show these?

Comment: Does gulp keep running in your console/terminal? Can you insert something like `gutil.log('watching');` into `gulp.task('watch:sass', function() {});` to check whether the task is called at all?

Comment: Hi @RodyvanSambeek, I shown the variable declarations of paths.

Comment: Thanks @insertusernamehere, I checked, the task is called.